# How to get the path of images from web folder

Tags: javascript, java, ios, gridview

Can anyone suggest me the tutorials or example links to get the relative path of the images from web folder to load it in gird view which supports for all mobile OS.
I am developing an cross platform app.

Comment: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I have misunderstood your question, but I read it as a question about where your images are stored or located in some sort of webview-based app that you are developing.

The simple answer is to open the project folder and search for `.jpg`, `.png`, or other common image file extensions.  On Windows or OS X, there should be a right-click (option-click) option to `show source folder`, `open file location` or something similar.

Once you know where the files are located in the project folder, read the file location (In Wondows, `C:\wherever_you_are`.  The file path should contain a `/www/` somewhere within it; ignore the `/www/` and everything before it, and that should be the relative path.

It may also be set up so that images can only be in the `/img/` subfolder, in which case, same as above for that folder.